# How to remove text notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have .txt file which has following data:

`test@gmail.com:afaf3114:asd335dfa`

`test@gmail.com:adadad141414:afa2115`

combo list with secret code how can i xchange in notepad++ to this

`test@gmail.com:afaf3114`

`test@gmail.com:adadad141414`

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Replace `:[^:]+$` with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

:[^:]+$ this method working

CTRL + F in notepad++

And put this :[^:]+$ - find what and select regular expressions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).